# How to tell a systemd initiated uWSGI daemon to use a specific python?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, uwsgi

I cobbled together the below **uWSGI** configuration file from examples online.
(◠﹏◠)

Given this configuration -- which resides in `/etc/uwsgi.d/myapp.ini` and which is used to start the `uwsgi` daemon and, in turn, `myapp` via `systemd/systemctl` -- which **configuration directive** do I use to tell it to use a specific virtual-environment PYTHON for `myapp`?

Is it `home =`?

In other words, when it invokes the `django.wsgi` application, how can I tell it (or how does it know) to use: `/home/myapp_unixHome/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/python`?

```
[uwsgi]

# =======================================================
# Directories ...
# =======================================================
home       =    /home/myapp_unixHome/.virtualenvs/myapp/  <--- Python virtualenv dir.
chdir      =    /home/myapp_unixHome/myapp/               <--- Django App here.
wsgi-file  =    /home/myapp_unixHome/myapp/django.wsgi    <--- Including this django.wsgi file.
static-map = /m=/home/myapp_unixHome/myapp/static/        <--- Static files.
# =======================================================

# =======================================================
# TO BE NAMED ...
# =======================================================
master = true
processes = 5
# =======================================================

# =======================================================
# myapp communicates w/ nginx via a UNIX domain socket.
# =======================================================
socket       = /run/uwsgi/myapp.sock
chmod-socket = 664
uid          = nginx
gid          = nginx
vacuum       = true
# =======================================================

# =======================================================
# uWSGI Log file.
# =======================================================
logto = /var/log/uwsgi.log
# =======================================================
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check in this link http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

```
home            = /path/to/virtualenv
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @gautamaggarwal . I looked all over for that (in the docs) but couldn't find it. Thank you.